# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$
[image]

[image]

I have two questions:

1). Why should we choose $R+2\pi i$? If I choose $R+\frac{\pi}{2}i$, then the pole wouldn't be in the region. What is the difference?

2).Why does he claim that the residue is $e^{i\pi a}\frac{d(1+e^z)}{dz}|z=i\pi$. What I was taught is to first decide what order is the pole which involves taking the inverse of the function and finding the order of zero of that function. Then multiplies the original function with $(z-i\pi)^k$, $k$ being the order, and take the $k$th derivative.

Comment: You are not evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx$ (that as soon as $a\neq 0$, does not really depend on $a$), you are computing something else. The title is misleading.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have edited it

Comment: Bad fix. Now the integral in the title does not even exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choose $R+2 \pi i$ because $F(z+2\pi i)=e^{2\pi i a}F(z)$, where $e^{2\pi i a}$ is a constant. If you use $F(z+\pi i/2)$, then you are adding up two integrals and you can not simplify the question.